# merging two elements from two list in random

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, data-structures

I am trying to randomly match two elements from list and tuple. My goal is to create a string with 1 to 1 match.

Below is the ideal code I am trying to achieve in the end.

```
>>> color = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow']
>>> transportation = ('car', 'train', 'airplane')
>>> combination(color, transportation)

['a red car', 'a yellow train', 'a orange airplane']
```

Here is what I have so far.

```
def combination(color, transportation):
    import random
    import itertools
    n = len(colors)
    new = random.sample(set(itertools.product(color, transportation)), n)
    return new

[('red', 'car'), ('orange', 'car'), ('red', 'airplane')]
```

As you can see, the color 'red' is being used twice and the transportation 'car' is also being used twice.

I am having trouble assigning each transportation to only one of the color and each color to only one of the transportation.

Also, I would really appreciate any tips on how to turn the tuple in to string.
ex) ('red', 'car') -> 'a red car' for every item i have in list.

Comment: See the random.shuffle() method (the "transportation  must be a list).

Comment: `'a orange airplane'` Are you sure it is really ideal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like that might work:

```
from random import shuffle

color = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow']
transportation = ('car', 'train', 'airplane')

t_list = list(transportation)
shuffle(color)
shuffle(t_list)

new_lst = list(zip(color, t_list))
print(new_lst)
#  [('red', 'train'), ('orange', 'car'), ('yellow', 'airplane')]
```

note that you have to convert `transportation` to a list for [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=shuffle#random.shuffle) work: `shuffle` modifies the list in-place.

as for the second part of your question: [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20join#str.join) will help:

```
for col_trans in new_lst:
    print(' '.join(col_trans))
# red train
# orange car
# yellow airplane
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this.

> Use `random.shuffle()` and `zip()`.

```
>>> import random
>>>
>>> color = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow']
>>> transportation = ('car', 'train', 'airplane')
>>>
>>> random.shuffle(color)
>>>
>>> list(zip(color, transportation))
[('yellow', 'car'), ('orange', 'train'), ('red', 'airplane')]
>>>
>>> random.shuffle(color)
>>> list(zip(color, transportation))
[('red', 'car'), ('yellow', 'train'), ('orange', 'airplane')]
>>>
>>> random.shuffle(color)
>>> list(zip(color, transportation))
[('orange', 'car'), ('red', 'train'), ('yellow', 'airplane')]
>>>
```